# Math.pow() on inputVal

Tags: javascript, html, web

I don't know how to use the `Math.pow()` when I have 1 variable that gets my inputs which is `inputVal`. This is how I did it.

```
else if(pow == true){
    if(equation.indexOf('^') == inputVal){
        inputVal = inputVal.replace('^', '');
        input.innerHTML = Math.pow(inputVal);
    }else{
        input.innerHTML = 'Syntax Error';
        pow = false;
    }
}
```

I tried to do this on my own, and it doesn't work.

I've also tried this

```
else if(pow == true){
    input.innerHTML = Math.pow(inputVal);
}else{
    pow = false;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is `equation.indexOf('^') == inputVal` supposed to do?

Comment: `Math.pow` requires two arguments. Are you trying to square it, or what?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate Math.pow(), It doesn't work. I have 'inputVal'

Comment: But what input do you expect to receive, and what're you trying to do with it?

Comment: And what is inputVal supposed to be? Because first you check if it's a number, and then you try to split it as though it's a string. It can't be both.

Comment: I'll upload a live version of the webpage on jsfiddle. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Jt8h5/

Comment: I think canon has what you want below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.pow() needs 2 parameters. 
If your inputVal is a a^b format
what you will need to do is

```
var piv = inputVal.indexOf("^");
var a = parseInt(inputVal.substring(0, piv));
var b = parseInt(inputVal.substring(piv+1));
input.innerHTML = Math.pow(a, b);
```

Please make sure your inputVal is a string. otherwise the string function wont work.
the comments from conan is correct. you can try parseFloat or even Number() function according to your needs.

Comment: `Math.pow()` accepts decimal values... so, consider `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`. That said, `Math.pow()` will happily coerce string arguments into numerical values, i.e.: `Math.pow(" 2.2", "4") // 23.425600000000006`

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, your input value is of the form `base^exponent`. So, split the input on `^` to get an array of arguments and then call `Math.pow()` using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), `...`; e.g.:

```js
console.log("result: %o", Math.pow(..."2^3".split("^")));
```

Comment: Oooh, that's what he's trying to do